# Which object owns react click handler code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, this

I know that when using React class methods arrow functions are a great way to lock in `this`. For example I might have a click handler:

```
clickHandler = () => {
    // some code using 'this'
    // eg this.state
}

// ... and in the render method
<button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}>Test Button</button>
```

However if I were to use a non-arrow function syntax what object owns the code? That is, what is `this`?

I have tried the following but Typescript will not compile:

```
clickHandler = function() {
    console.log(this);   // also tried to coerce this as any type  
}

// Error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you call the function and whether or not you bind it.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    clickHandler = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Option A</button>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>Option B</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}>Option C</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

With the `Option A` button, the click handler is passed directly to the `<button />` element. Since React assumes you bind `this` and won't do it for you, the `this` inside `clickHandler` will be `undefined`.

With the `Option B` button we're explicitly binding `this.clickHandler` to `this`, in which case the `this` inside `clickHandler` will refer to that specific instance of the `Test` component.

For `Option C` (which is what you're doing in your question) we are not setting `this.clickHandler` as the `onClick` handler, but we're defining a *new arrow function* that *calls* `this.clickHandler`. In this case, the new arrow function will automatically get the `Test` component as `this` and that one is passed along to `clickHandler`.

Note that the `Option A` version will allow components to explicitly bind the handler:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button
                onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(this)}
                children={this.props.children}
            />
        );
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
    clickHandler = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    render() {
        return <Button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Click</Button>;
    }
}
```

In this case, `this` within `Test.clickHandler()` will actually be a reference to the `Button` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your "this" will be 'undefined' because React calls your function behind the scenes and it `doesn't` call it from the object instance (I.E `MyComponent.onClickHandler(e)`) it calls it like this `(onClickHandler(e))`

A simplified model of what's happening without React involved looks something like this.....

```
class FakeReactComponent {
  myName() {
     console.log(this);
  }
}
// this is what you give a onClick prop on an element.
const functionPassedToOnClick= new FakeReactComponent().myName;

console.log(
  functionPassedToOnClick() // this is how react calls it (this is undefined)
)
```

On method to get around this is to bind "this" of the function in the constructor of the component I.E

```
constructor(props: IProps) {
     super(props);
     this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
}
```

This is actually the 'best practice' way to define all functions within a `class` for React Components as arrow functions don't go on the classes prototype and therefore fresh functions are created for every new React instance of that component; however with non-arrow functions each instance goes on the prototype and therefore reused for each react component instance.

Tricks like autobind are also not best practice because binding every function's `this` is unneccessary because only functions being called by React need to have their `this` bound and 99% of the time that's only functions being used as event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone else who doesn't understand why 'undefined' appears here, as it was for me, then check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918107/using-a-class-method-in-the-global-context-has-this-as-undefined?noredirect=1#comment100378952_56918107