# Using a class method in the Global context has `this` as undefined

Tags: javascript, class, this, global

I have a class, which has a method that uses `this`. I 'newed up' an instance of this object and passed on its method to a variable in the global context. If I then call my global function `this` is undefined.

```
class Tests {
  logThis() {
     console.log(this);
  }
}

const globalFunc = new Test().logThis;

globalFunc(); // undefined
```

Now, if I had just used an object literal then `this` is is global.

```
const someObject= {
    logThis2: function() {console.log(this)}
}

const globalFunc2 = someObject.logThis2;

globalFunc2(); // global object
```

In both cases the global object owns the code and should be supplying `this` in the `globalFunc` execution context. So why the difference in `this` for a class generated method?

Comment: JavaScript classes are always in strict mode. Other functions / contexts are not in strict mode unless there is a `"use strict";` statement. In strict mode `this` is `undefined` instead of the global object when it has not been specified.

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro . So what about when the method is assigned. Is the original `this` also bound to the method.

Comment: No, see this question for information about `this` in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work . functions don't get a `this` bound to them. `this` is determined at the time the function is called, not when the function is defined. `x.foo()` calls the function `x.foo` with `this === x`. `var y = { bar: x.foo }; y.bar( );` calls `x.foo` with `this === y`. Whereas `var z = x.foo; z( );` calls `x.foo`, with no `this`, which will cause it to be `undefined` in strict mode but for legacy/bc reasons it will be the global object in non-strict mode.

Comment: You are storing a reference to the prototype  , not to a direct property of the instance object. Would have to make `logThis` a direct property in the class constructor to do what you want.  `constructor(){
         this.logThis = this.logThis.bind(this)
      }`

Comment: Sorry @Paulpro I still don't get it cause in your example z is not in a class (ie not in strict mode) and is in the global context. That is the state of things at the time of the call???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `class`es, including their methods are evaluated in strict mode¹. Whenever a function gets created, and "its body is in strict mode"², then the function's internal [[mode]] property gets set to "strict". That will then let `this` evaluate to `undefined` when the function gets called without a context.

---

Relevant quotes from the spec:

1:

> All parts of a ClassDeclaration or a ClassExpression are strict mode code

~ ES 262, 10.2.1 Strict Mode Code

---

2:

> 3. If the function code for this MethodDefinition is strict mode code, let strict be true. Otherwise let strict be false.
>
> [...]
>
> 7. Let closure be FunctionCreate(kind, UniqueFormalParameters, FunctionBody, scope, strict, prototype).
> 8. Perform MakeMethod(closure, object).

~ ES 262, 14.3.7 Runtime Semantics: DefineMethod